# Showing that $\pi:C_0(Y) \rightarrow L(C_b(X))$, continuous representation of $C_0(Y)$ on $C_0(X)$ is nondegenerate

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

Consider $\alpha: C_b(X) \rightarrow L(C_0(X))$(set of bounded operators) defined as $\alpha(f)(g) := f \cdot g$, this is nondegenerate i.e. the closure of $\text{span}\{f \cdot g:f \in C_b(X), g \in C_0(X)\}$ is equal to $C_0(X)$. One can see this by noticing that given $h \in C_0(X)$, then $h = 1 \cdot h \in \text{span}\{f \cdot g:f \in C_b(X), g \in C_0(X)\}$.It should be noted that $C_0(X)$ is a closed ideal of $C_b(X)$

Let $X$ and $Y$ be both locally compact. Define $F$ to be a continuous function from $X$ to $Y$, and a homomorphism $\Phi:C_0(Y) \rightarrow C_b(X)$ defined as $$\Phi(g)(x) := g(F(x))$$And, $\pi:C_0(Y) \rightarrow L(C_0(X))$ defined as $$\pi(g)(f) := \Phi(g)f$$More explicitly we can see that $$\pi(g)(f)(x) = \Phi(g)(x) \cdot f(x)$$The span $$S := \text{span} \{\pi(g)(f): g \in C_0(Y), f \in C_0(X)\} \subset C_0(X)$$We want to show that $$C_0(X) \subset \overline{S}$$Given $f \in C_\infty(X)$, we want to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $h \in S$ such that $||f - h||_\infty < \epsilon$.

I tried using partition of unity to try construct $h$, but it didn't seem to work, and it's too annoying to write down everything I did. I was wondering if the way is trivial? I was thinking of using the fact that that $\text{span}\{f \cdot g:f \in C_b(X), g \in C_0(X)\} = C_0(X)$. And use the fact that $\Phi(g) \in C_b(X)$.

Comment: What is $C_{\infty}(X)$? Also, have you tried applying the Stone-Weierstrass theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C_c(X)$, the space of compactly supported functions on $X$, is dense in $C_0(X)$, so it suffices to show $C_c(X) \subseteq S$. Let $f \in C_c(X)$ with support $K \subseteq X$, where $K$ is compact. Then $F(K)$ is compact. By Urysohn's lemma, there exists $g \in C_0(Y)$ s.t. $g(F(K)) = 1$. Hence, $\pi(g)(f) = f$, so $f \in S$.